# How to properly draw text with "Core Text" in flipped NSView

Tags: cocoa, core-text

I use my own NSView with

```
- (BOOL) isFlipped { return TRUE; }
```

to have left-top-based coordinate.
The problem is then I draw text with Core Text:

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(descriptor, size, NULL);
CFAttributedStringRef attrStr = makeAttrStringRef(str, font);
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrStr);
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, pos.x, pos.y); // pos is left-top corener
CTLineDraw(line, context);
```

the text is flipped:

[image]

If I pass flipped matrix to `CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor`

```
CGAffineTransform flipped = (CGAffineTransform){1,0,0,-1,0,0};
```

the text is shifted (left-top corner of text if not at `pos`):

[image]

What is a proper way to draw text in flipped NSView with keeping left-top-based coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You always must initialize the text matrix before rendering text, typically to identity:

```
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
```

It's been a little while, so I can't remember immediately if you need to flip it for a flipped view on macOS. (If you have trouble, add a comment and I'll dredge up the right transform.)

Comment: Thx. I have try your suggestion. Setting `CGContextSetTextMatrix` looks fully equal to pass the same transform matrix `CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor`. So problem keeps: if passed matrix is flipped then left-top corner of text if not at `pos` (left-bottom corner is at `pos`).

Comment: Ah, now I see the question, better. No, text will always draw anchored near the lower left. That's how the text layout system works. You have to write your algorithms to deal with that because characters are different heights.

Comment: @RobNapier - I am having trouble getting Core Text to draw properly on MacOS.  In my test app it works fine but in a scrollView it shows up upside down and characters on top of each other.  If I initialise using Identity matrix the text dissapears somewhere !  Happy to post a new question is necessary.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald I'd open a new question, but do make sure you're not flipping the context. If you're using code from iOS, it often flips the context, but macOS generally should not do this. If the identity matrix makes the text disappear, it's probably winding up outside the view.

Comment: @RobNapier - thanks.  It seems I just got lucky with my prototype where for some reason the CTFrame draws properly without setting the textMatrix.  I finally figured it out by drawing the boundingBox and tracking down the rising text - pretty much as you mentioned - ended up drawing so small as to be invisible!  Still it seems one can't create a cgPath for the text frame and then later just scale/rotate it and draw it - I have to recreate the frame each drawing operation - which seems inefficient.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, `CTFramesetter` does a lot of work for you. If you want to do it by hand, see http://robnapier.net/laying-out-text-with-coretext